# Does the ordering of the QueryList from @ViewChildren always match with the ordering in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have a few `my-component`s and I would like to query a list of them:

```
<li><my-component>#1</my-component><li>
<li><my-component>#2</my-component><li>
<li><my-component>#3</my-component><li>
```

Using `@ViewChildren` I can get a list (for example through `.toArray`) that might look like the following:

```
[
    /* reference to #1 component*/,
    /* reference to #2 component*/,
    /* reference to #3 component*/
]
```

My only concern here is that I am not sure whether the order will always be the same as it is in the DOM. [The documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#description) does not mention anything regarding the ordering. The order matters in my case because I am trying to select the component with a given index.

Does the ordering of the QueryList set by `@ViewChildren` always match with the ordering in the DOM?

Comment: Yes, they matches with the ordering of the DOM.

Comment: but you can re-order if you want. just convert to array, sort the array and use reset https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#reset

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It does not always match the DOM-order.

If items are moved or added run time, the order of the QueryList will be off. This happened to me in an @angular/material table with drag-drop.

To solve it, you have to call reset on the QueryList passing sorted child items. This is one way you could to that by subscribing to QueryList-changes:

```
const rowChange$: Observable<QueryList<MatRow>> = this.rows.changes;

const indexOfRow = (row: MatRow) => {
  return [...this._elementRef.nativeElement.children].indexOf(row.elementRef.nativeElement);
};

const sortedRows$ = rowChange$.pipe(
  map(rows => rows.toArray()),
  filter(rows => rows.length > 1),
  map(rows => rows.sort((a, b) => indexOfRow(a) - indexOfRow(b)))
);

sortedRows$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroySub))
  .subscribe(sortedRows => this.rows.reset(sortedRows));
```